# The value stored in the hashmap did not change,why?

Tags: java

I think I passed the reference of value to hashmap,then after I change the value outside,the value in the hashmap should also be changed.

```
    Integer key=new Integer(0);
    Integer value=new Integer(3);
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    hm.put(key, value);
    System.out.println(hm.get(key));
    value=null;
    System.out.println(hm.get(key));
```

Comment: You are not changing the value of `Integer value` you are changing its reference, and `Integer` is immutable, so you will need another `put` to replace

Comment: Java is pass by value and not by reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value